# will it be harder to find a hosting company if I use Django with Python?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, hosting

I'd like to go into Django with Python, but it seems that some hosting companies like [DreamHost](http://www.dreamhost.com/r.cgi?542295), [Netfirms](http://affiliates.netfirms.com/e.asp?e=8&id=6738), they both offer Ruby on Rails in the basic hosting package, but not Django.  They only list Python, but not the framework.  So does that mean if I use Django, I will need to look for companies that support Django, or can I simply add the Django files to my directory and it will work without using any other support?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [Djangofriendly.com](http://www.Djangofriendly.com) for a list of hosts that are friendly to setting up Django (not that you can't do it with many other hosts, of course).

Personally, I have a few Django apps hosted on [Webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com) and they are absolutely amazing.

Answer (score 5):

[Dreamhost does support Django!](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/Django)

And here's a [list of hosting companies which support Django](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoFriendlyWebHosts), and as you see, most major companies support it.

Answer (score 3):

It would be harder in the sense that the number of choices you have will be smaller.  But the reality is that you need only one host anyway.

I highly recommend [Webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com/) as my experience with them has been very good.  They support Django out of the box with very little configuration necessary on your side.

Check these lists for Django hosts:
http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoFriendlyWebHosts
http://djangohosting.org/

Comment: For some reason S.O. put me down for a down-vote on this response and now won't let me change it, saying it was too long ago. Big fan of WebFaction and appreciate hekevintran posting the Django hosting list. Consider this an up-vote (be great if some admin type would make the change.)

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that most shared hosting packages will not be suitable for Django, because of the need to restart the server whenever you make changes to python code - most don't allow this. Webfaction is a notable exception - I am using them for several Django projects, and would second the recommendations above. You barely notice it's a shared host.

But you might want to consider virtualized hosting. I also have some projects hosted at [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/). The prices are comparable to a shared host and you have complete control over your server. This also means, of course, that setting things up is less one-click, although they provide great step-by-step tutorials.

Comment: I'm a big fan of Slicehost. For only $20 a month I get the equivalent of having a server running in the corner of my house without any of the hassle of maintaining uptime and connectivity myself.

Their terms of service are great, too.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could look into [Googles app engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) if you want to do python web development. They can handle all the hosting for you.

Comment: With App Engine, you're forced to cope with Google's non-relational data store. If your app fits with that, great. Many don't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

The standard hosting packages are either  Windows/ISS or Linux/php/perl/Mysql.

There are a few specialist Django/python hosting packages, but, your best bet is
to get a Linux VPS (Virtual Private Server) package which gives you root access.

You can then install exactly what you require. Prices start at less $10 a month
for a basic low bandwith not much disk space package.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on compared to what. If it is compared to Rails, it will be harder just because of the buzz around Rails and it is quite likely a "basic" package would include Rails before Django, so if that cost factor matters, be aware of it, but there is pleanty of competition for Django hosting, so the lack of hosting isn't a reason to avoid it.

PHP is much more popular to host at the basic level, if hosting drives the technology decision.